# Reactjs rendeing of component after parse find query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, reactjs

I am trying to do is when the page is being loaded it should bring all the data from the parse.com database and display it on the page and I want to render my component after my find request is done.

Below you can see my code

```
var Ap = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
      Parse.initialize("mSWrLtmIHQdh8CNGk14fLbnK4gaVDbgvjw1zTeCT", "qKDkELvVpvgkuDDZzGK2pdP5o69LBDjWaRI2XfUb");
      var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");

      var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
      var x;
      query.find({
      success: function(results) {
          //debugger;
         var cells = [];
         for (var i in results) {
            cells.push(<tr><td>"foo"</td><td>{i.attributes.foo}</td></tr>);}
        return (
          <div id="second-div">
            <table>
              {cells}
            </table> 
          </div>
          )

      },

      error: function(error) {
        return(<div></div>)

      }
});
    }

  }
  );

  React.renderComponent(<Ap/>,  document.body);

</script>
```

But i get the error below because i am returning render inside the done method of my find query.

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Ap.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Is there a way to wait for my find query to end before start rendering

and I'm also having another which I was not able to understand

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined

Since I'm new to reactjs and parse so any help would be appreciated

Comment: `push(<tr><td>"foo"</td><td>{i.attributes.foo}</td></tr>)` quote it properly.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I did'nt get what you are trying to say

Comment: will `push(<tr>)` work? not. `push('<tr>')` will.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal  oh I see. But I'm still encountering the ap.render error

Comment: First of all, your `render` method should not be used to implement logic besides the view one. Secondly, it should return a component. You're returning an object.

Comment: @Bwaxxlo can you point me to a solution or something from which I'll be able to solve my problem

Comment: @BhojendraNepal  `push(<tr></tr>)` is totally fine in JSX, just like what you can do in `return <tr></tr>`

Comment: @james Your `render` function should return something (specifically, a react component). At the moment, it's not returning anything, let alone a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a request in component's componentDidMount method and assign the results to component's state. This will cause component's rendering.

In render method read the data from the state.

```
var Ap = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            data: []
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        var that = this;
        Parse.initialize("mSWrLtmIHQdh8CNGk14fLbnK4gaVDbgvjw1zTeCT", "qKDkELvVpvgkuDDZzGK2pdP5o69LBDjWaRI2XfUb");
        var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");

        var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);

        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                that.setState({
                    data: results
                });
            },
            error: function(error) {
                that.setState({
                    data: []
                });

            }
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        var cells = [];
        for (var i in this.state.data) {
            cells.push(<tr><td>"foo"</td><td>{this.state.data[i].attributes.foo}</td></tr>);
        }
        return (
          <div id="second-div">
            <table>
              {cells}
            </table> 
          </div>
          )
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Ap/>,  document.body);
```

Comment: this is giving me this error  **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Comment: Oh, forgot about 'this' binding, sorry. I modified code in my initial answer, please try again.

Comment: it's not displaying anything now . not even an error in the console. Everything seems to working perfectly fine but nothing is being displayed

Comment: is there any chance that if it is not being displayed because it is unable to find jquery.min.js ??

Comment: I'm not sure about jQuery, but I don't think so. Try debugging your application using Chrome Dev Tools, look at the contents of the state object on render method to make sure that the data is there.

Comment: it started working because it was not loading parse file how but it's giving me this error now **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined**

Comment: You may get it because you are accessing the wrong object in your for loop. If results is an array, then 'i' is the element's index. In this case it should be this.state.data[i].attributes.foo instead of i.attributes.foo.

Comment: Thanks yes this was the problem I was facing. I just have one more request that can you tell me why is your code work and not mine. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean what's wrong with putting the logic into 'render' method? It's just wrong, it's not React way. You should 'tell' the component what data to display by setting its state or props, and the render method renders these data into DOM. That's the correct way to work with React. Refer to the docs about component lifecycle to understand how it works: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Answer (score 1):

1. The problem is you returned `undefined` from your `render()`. Because after an ajax call there is no more code and `render()` had to return `undefined` that caused the error. You could put the query into `componentDidMount()` or some methods running earlier or some parent components/outer code and pass props to `<Ap />` or set its state.
2. `{i.attributes.foo}` may cause the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined`. Thus your `i.attributes` was `undefined` instead of some meaningful object such as `results[i].attributes`.

Comment: But in the success portion I'm returning the code and even in the error portion I'm returning a div

Comment: I guess the `query.find()` call [is](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/event-based-programming-what-async-has-over-sync--net-30027) [asynchronous](http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/)